# Calling a Select_List with Watir-Webdriver Without an ID/Name

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm currently having trouble calling a Select_List that does not have a name/ID (as the title states).

The HTML for the Select List is:

```
<select dojoattachpoint="userSelector" size="15" multiple="">

  <option value="_W2kn2sdAEeSmeMQKjIY8Ug"></option>
  <option value="_gkeqUBUqEeG7h6M2lwbcyg"></option>

</select>
```

What I need to do is select one option in the select list and then click a button, but I can't select the option if I don't know how to point at the list itself.

Note: This is done in Firefox if it matters.

Comment: If the strings for the value attributes aren't dynamic, you could use [`Select::select_value`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#select_value-instance_method).

Comment: @orde
Unfortunately, I have no idea how the values for the options are generated. Based on how I'm doing the script, there should only be one option to select from (It's a user list and I'm searching based on userid).
I'm not just sure how to select the option if I can't identify the select_list first.

Comment: Right on.  I misunderstood your question, anyway.  At least you got the answer you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "dojoattachpoint" is not a valid attribute for a Select Element per the html5 spec, you can't use it directly. You can access it with css, though:
`el = browser.select(css: "[dojoattachpoint='userSelector']")`
You could also look into making the site's code html5 compliant, since I think dojo supports data tags: 'data-dojoattachpoint' or the like. Then your selector could be: `el = browser.select(data_dojoattachpoint: 'userSelector')`

Comment: This worked! Thanks a bunch. is (css: "[whatever= 'whateverelse']") the way to point towards elements with custom attributes?

Comment: Not if it is a valid html5 attribute for that tag, in which case you can call it directly: ```browser.html5element(supported_attr: "foo")```